# In python how to fix the code when it is executing fine (exit code 0) but with no results (nothing printing)?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape the webpage of the new york times. My code is running fine as it is showing exit code 0 but giving no results.

```
import time

import requests

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.nytimes.com/search?endDate=20190331&query=cybersecurity&sort=newest&startDate=20180401={}'

pages = [0]

for page in pages:
    res = requests.get(url.format(page))
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"lxml")
    for item in soup.select("#search-results li > a"):
        resp = requests.get(item.get("href"))
        sauce = BeautifulSoup(resp.text, "lxml")
        date = sauce.select(".css-1vkm6nb ehdk2mb0 h1")
        date = date.text
        print(date)

        time.sleep(3)
```

with this code, I am hoping to get the publish date from each article.

Comment: if nothing is printing, the obvious culprit is that one or more of your `select` statements are incorrect, and not returning an iterable. So, add more `print` or logging statements earlier in the process to identify what's happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nice attempt--you're pretty close. The problem is the selectors:

1. `#search-results` asks for an id that doesn't exist. The element is a `<ol data-testid="search-results">`, so we'll need other means to grab this anchor tag.
2. `.css-1vkm6nb ehdk2mb0 h1` doesn't make much sense. It asks for an element `h1` that is inside of a `ehdk2mb0` element which is inside of an element with the class `.css-1vkm6nb`. What's actually on the page is an `<h1 class="css-1vkm6nb ehdk2mb0">` element. Select this with `h1.css-1vkm6nb.ehdk2mb0`.

Having said that, this is not the time data you're after--it's the title. We can get the time element (`<time>`) with a simple `sauce.find("time")`.

Full example:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

base = "https://www.nytimes.com"
url = "https://www.nytimes.com/search?endDate=20190331&query=cybersecurity&sort=newest&startDate=20180401={}"

pages = [0]

for page in pages:
    res = requests.get(url.format(page))
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"lxml")

    for link in soup.select(".css-138we14 a"):
        resp = requests.get(base + link.get("href"))
        sauce = BeautifulSoup(resp.text, "lxml")
        title = sauce.select_one("h1.css-1j5ig2m.e1h9rw200")
        time = sauce.find("time")
        print(time.text, title.text.encode("utf-8"))
```

Output:

```
March 30, 2019 b'Bezos\xe2\x80\x99 Security Consultant Accuses Saudis of Hacking the Amazon C.E.O.\xe2\x80\x99s Phone'
March 29, 2019 b'In Ukraine, Russia Tests a New Facebook Tactic in Election Tampering'
March 28, 2019 b'Huawei Shrugs Off U.S. Clampdown With a $100 Billion Year'
March 28, 2019 b'N.S.A. Contractor Arrested in Biggest Breach of U.S. Secrets Pleads Guilty'
March 28, 2019 b'Grindr Is Owned by a Chinese Firm, and the U.S. Is Trying to Force It to Sell'
March 28, 2019 b'DealBook Briefing: Saudi Arabia Wanted Cash. Aramco Just Obliged.'
March 28, 2019 b'Huawei Security \xe2\x80\x98Defects\xe2\x80\x99 Are Found by British Authorities'
March 25, 2019 b'As Special Counsel, Mueller Kept Such a Low Profile He Seemed Almost Invisible'
March 21, 2019 b'Quotation of the Day: In New Age of Digital Warfare, Spies for Any Nation\xe2\x80\x99s Budget'
March 21, 2019 b'Coast Guard\xe2\x80\x99s Top Officer Pledges \xe2\x80\x98Dedicated Campaign\xe2\x80\x99 to Improve Diversity'
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Thank you for encouragement. As you must have understood I am just the beginner in programming or coding. Just one more question why in title it is showing "\xe2\x80\x99s". Is there way to slove this?

Comment: No problem. The string contains unicode, so printing it raises a UnicodeDecodeError. How you handle it might depend on what you ultimately plan on doing with the data. If you're writing it to file or CSV, you can probably just write it directly without problem.

Comment: This code finish after March 21, 2019. But I want to grab date and title for all the 335 entries. Usually there are different pages but in this case, all articles are on a single page, still, I can access all the article. How to get all the article in this kind of case?

Comment: Well, the "show more" button, if that's what you're referring to, makes a server request and the data for more articles is loaded via JS. You'll need to use something like Selenium to dynamically navigate and extract text from the page in real time. I'd recommend opening up a fresh question for that if you get stuck, because BeautifulSoup/requests aren't going to be of much help.